# Position of buttons besides image

Tags: html, css

I have single image and 5 buttons, I would like to position the at the **top-right** side of the image, the buttons should be one **above the other**. currently the buttons are at bottom right side of the image and placed in a row.

```js
function pictureChange(imgId, path) {
  document.getElementById(imgId).src = path;
}
```

```css
p {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<img id="scene1" src="images/scene1/scene1-4dof.png">

<p>
  <input type="button" value="4DOF" onclick="pictureChange('scene1','images/scene1/scene1-4dof.png')">
</p>
<p>
  <input type="button" value="6DOF" onclick="pictureChange('scene1','images/scene1/scene1-6dof.png')">
</p>
<p>
  <input type="button" value="6DOF-PCA" onclick="pictureChange('scene1','images/scene1/scene1-6dof-pca.png')">
</p>
<p>
  <input type="button" value="7DOF" onclick="pictureChange('scene1','images/scene1/scene1-7dof.png')">
</p>
<p>
  <input type="button" value="7DOF-PCA" onclick="pictureChange('scene1','images/scene1/scene1-7dof-pca.png')">
</p>
```

Comment: Have you actually tried adding any css to the code?

Comment: SpaceMan, I don't know if you know how to use CSS, but CSS is all you ever need to fix any of your graphical problems, including positioning, making it look better, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
function pictureChange(imgId,path) {
  document.getElementById(imgId).src=path;
}
```

```css
.sid {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

img {
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
}

.sid input {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<img class="sid" id="scene1" src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x200">
<!---->
<div class="sid">
  <input type="button" value="4DOF" onclick="pictureChange('scene1','images/scene1/scene1-4dof.png')">
  <input type="button" value="6DOF" onclick="pictureChange('scene1','images/scene1/scene1-6dof.png')">
  <input type="button" value="6DOF-PCA" onclick="pictureChange('scene1','images/scene1/scene1-6dof-pca.png')">
  <input type="button" value="7DOF" onclick="pictureChange('scene1','images/scene1/scene1-7dof.png')">
  <input type="button" value="7DOF-PCA" onclick="pictureChange('scene1','images/scene1/scene1-7dof-pca.png')">
</div>
```

What I did is add `display: inline-block;` to the image and the div 'i added to contain the inputs'

This `<!---->` for `inline` behaviour in `inline-block` ' shows any spacing between elements '

also `vertical-align: top;` for the top part of top-right

Comment: do you want the input on top of the image  top-right??

Answer (score 1):

This solution will scale according to the surrounding element. To show this I added an extra wrapper.

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative; 
  /* width of the image here */
}
.wrapper .buttons {
  position: absolute;
  right: 3%;
  top: 3%;
}
#scene1 {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <img id="scene1" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
  <div class="buttons">
    <p><input type="button" value="4DOF" onclick="pictureChange('scene1','images/scene1/scene1-4dof.png')"></p>
    <p><input type="button" value="6DOF" onclick="pictureChange('scene1','images/scene1/scene1-6dof.png')"></p>
    <p><input type="button" value="6DOF-PCA" onclick="pictureChange('scene1','images/scene1/scene1-6dof-pca.png')"></p>
    <p><input type="button" value="7DOF" onclick="pictureChange('scene1','images/scene1/scene1-7dof.png')"></p>
    <p><input type="button" value="7DOF-PCA" onclick="pictureChange('scene1','images/scene1/scene1-7dof-pca.png')"></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Pure Css :**

**1) Buttons on image:**

```css
div {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

img {
    width:300px;
    border:1px solid #000;
}

.right {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div>
<img id="scene1" src="http://justcuteanimals.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/baby-bear-pictures-cute-animal-pics.jpg">
<div class="right">
<p><input type="button" value="4DOF" onclick="pictureChange('scene1','images/scene1/scene1-4dof.png')"></p>
<p><input type="button" value="6DOF" onclick="pictureChange('scene1','images/scene1/scene1-6dof.png')"></p>
<p><input type="button" value="6DOF-PCA" onclick="pictureChange('scene1','images/scene1/scene1-6dof-pca.png')"></p>
<p><input type="button" value="7DOF" onclick="pictureChange('scene1','images/scene1/scene1-7dof.png')"></p>
<p><input type="button" value="7DOF-PCA" onclick="pictureChange('scene1','images/scene1/scene1-7dof-pca.png')"></p>
</div>
</div>
```

**2) Buttons after image:**

```css
div {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

img {
    width:200px;
    border:1px solid #000;
}

.right {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: top;

}
```

```html
<div>
<img id="scene1" src="http://justcuteanimals.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/baby-bear-pictures-cute-animal-pics.jpg">
<div class="right">
<p><input type="button" value="4DOF" onclick="pictureChange('scene1','images/scene1/scene1-4dof.png')"></p>
<p><input type="button" value="6DOF" onclick="pictureChange('scene1','images/scene1/scene1-6dof.png')"></p>
<p><input type="button" value="6DOF-PCA" onclick="pictureChange('scene1','images/scene1/scene1-6dof-pca.png')"></p>
<p><input type="button" value="7DOF" onclick="pictureChange('scene1','images/scene1/scene1-7dof.png')"></p>
<p><input type="button" value="7DOF-PCA" onclick="pictureChange('scene1','images/scene1/scene1-7dof-pca.png')"></p>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function pictureChange(imgId,path) {
  document.getElementById(imgId).src=path;
}
```

```css
.img_con{
  width:400px;
  height:400px;
  position: relative;
}
.sid {
  position: absolute;

}

img {
  width:400px;
  height:400px;
}
.onTop{
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  right: 0;
}
.sid input {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="img_con">
  <img class="sid" id="scene1" src="http://via.placeholder.com/400x400">
  <div class="sid onTop">
    <input type="button" value="4DOF" onclick="pictureChange('scene1','images/scene1/scene1-4dof.png')">
    <input type="button" value="6DOF" onclick="pictureChange('scene1','images/scene1/scene1-6dof.png')">
    <input type="button" value="6DOF-PCA" onclick="pictureChange('scene1','images/scene1/scene1-6dof-pca.png')">
    <input type="button" value="7DOF" onclick="pictureChange('scene1','images/scene1/scene1-7dof.png')">
    <input type="button" value="7DOF-PCA" onclick="pictureChange('scene1','images/scene1/scene1-7dof-pca.png')">
  </div>
</div>
```